# I want to show the **href** context 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 via python selenium library

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to show the **href** context 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 via python selenium library, but the following coding cannot click the link, please help !

URL link:

```
 https://tmpfiles.org/dl/63714/example_2021.html
```

HTML code

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="GGGGG">
<div class="AAAAA">
<a href="#" class="BBBBB BBBBB" rel="11-11-1111|2222-22-22" style="display: block;"><i class="FFFFF FFFFF"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="AAAAA">
<span class="IIIII" id="HHHHH">11-11-1111</span>
</div>
<div class="AAAAA">
<a href="#" class="CCCCC CCCCC" rel="" style="display: none;"><i class="EEEEE EEEEE"></i></a>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div id="AAAAA" class="AAAAA"><div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dno">1</a></div> <div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dno">2</a></div> <div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dno">3</a></div> <div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dno">4</a></div> <div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dno">5</a></div> <div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dno">6</a></div> <div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dno">7</a></div> <div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dno">8</a></div> <div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dno">9</a></div> <div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dno on">10</a></div> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Python code

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("AAAAA")[0].click()
```

I can list out by following code:

```
c =  driver.find_elements_by_class_name("AAAAA")
d = []
for x in range (len(c)):
    d.append(c[x].text)
print(d)
```

result of this coding:

```
[]
```

Error Message from the code:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <div class="AAAAA"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Expected Result

```
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: so when you click 1, it must redirect somewhere right ? How are you coming back to main page to click on 2 ? and what is `a` in your code ? I see `1` is present twice.

Comment: Which line is causing `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'` ? Cause this looks okay to me `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("AAAAA")[0].click()`

Comment: dear, typo, "1" just in only one row

Comment: dear, updated the error message

Comment: dear, yes, click 1, will redirect somewhere

Comment: so I would like to ask when you click on `1`, it will redirect you where ? to a new tab or window ? or in the same page ?

Comment: dear, it should be same page

Comment: you can try the below solution, and I see you are using `rno`, where as in HTML it's `dno`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work here:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='AAAAA' and @class='AAAAA']//a")
for link in links:
    link.click()
```

You will obviously have to put some delay / wait before this code block to ensure the page is fully loaded before you getting all these elements.
**UPD**
If you need to print these links texts you can do this:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='AAAAA' and @class='AAAAA']//a")
for link in links:
    print(link.text)
```

Comment: dear, i put time.sleep(20) it seem not work, anyway, thanks !

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What error do you see for what code line?

Comment: nothing there, using this code links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='AAAAA' and @class='AAAAA']//a")
for link in links:
    print(link)

Comment: Sure, each `link` is a web element. If you want to print their texts you should extract them.

Comment: Also, verify if there is no iframe there or something similar i.e. the elements are accessible

Comment: I guess she wanted to click on them one by one right  ?

Comment: Initially I thought that too.

Comment: dear, yes @cruisepandey

Answer (score 1):

If it's in the same page then I guess it must scroll down till certain point to display content :

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
c =  driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rno")
for ele in c:
    action.move_to_element(ele).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

in case you need bit more scrolling, you can try the below solution :

```
for ele in c:
    action.move_to_element(ele).click().perform()
    sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100)")
```

**udpate 1 :**

```
c =  driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.AAAAA a")
d = []
for x in range (len(c)):
    d.append(x.text)
print(d)
```

Comment: dear, it not work, but i don't know why cannot print out elements by this code c =  driver.find_elements_by_class_name("AAAAA")
d = []
for x in range (len(c)):
    d.append(c[x].text)
print(d)

Comment: Check out the update 1 code section above.

Comment: dear, it still not work, anyway, thanks !

Comment: Can you share URL  if possible  ?

Comment: dear, can i select both <div id="AAAAA" class="AAAAA"> @ selenium, since i find some duplicated for class="AAAAA

Comment: dear, it code like driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="AAAAA" and @class="AAAAA"]')

Comment: yes if you want xpath, then you can do `//div[@id='AAAAA' and @class='AAAAA']`

Comment: Mary, you would need to take care of double quotes

Comment: dear, noted, but it seem cannot be solved, anyway, thanks !

Comment: Can I have the URL ?>

Comment: dear, actually no URL, i just using my self coding to do that, thanks